# Creating .inf file from command line (using msbuild)

Tags: windows-mobile, msbuild

I would like to create .inf file (for creating .cab file) using msbuild command line.

First I tried to rebuild the solution using VS IDE and it created .inf file which could be used to create .cab file (package for mobile device). Then I tried to create .inf file with msbuild with the following command:

```
msbuild solutionName.sln /p:platform="Windows Mobile 6 Professional SDK (ARMV4I)" /t:rebuild"
```

It successfully rebuilt the solution and all the projects but it didn't create the .inf file inside deployment project directory.

Does anyone know how to create the .inf file from command line?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I assume you mean that the solution contains a Smart Device CAB project and that project is not getting built?  Unfortunately the CAB project (and the regular desktop installs for that matter) are somewhat of an aberration.  They are plug-ins to Studio that actually don't interact with msbuild, and are not directly automatable. You instead have to hack in an Exec command to run devenv, pass in the args, and then copy out your results.  [See this article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms404859.aspx) on the procedures for a desktop installer.  The same process works for device projects too.

This is the exact reason we still hand-build the INF and [run cabwiz independently](http://blog.opennetcf.com/ctacke/2008/09/18/AutomatingCABFileGenerationWithMSBUILD.aspx).